# Photoelectric effect and electron loss

Tags: atoms, electrons

I've read that when a certain amount of UV light is shone on a metal surface, electrons are ejected (the photoelectric effect).

Are these electrons from the metal atoms themselves? and in case they are - what happens to the metal atoms seen as they have lost an electron? (Are they chemically different?)

Comment: You may find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect and especially http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT the amount of light (number of photons), it is the energy of each photon (its frequency).  When the energy of a photon exceeds the vacuum work function of the surface, an electron is unbound.  There obtains a charged surface and a free electron.  Unless the surface is part of a circuit (e.g., grounded or connected to the cathode), the next electron out must overcome the vacuum work function plus the electrical potential.

The electron is emitted from the conduction band of the bulk metal surface.  The positive charge is delocalized across the surface if it is of constant radius of curvature.   Surface electric field divergence is inversely proportional to radius of curvature.  Unless the surface is very smooth you can get cold cathode emission or electrical breakdown of the encapsulating medium.