# Photoelectric Effect

Tags: electrons

So If i were to define what the photoelectric effect is,
is it when light is shined on a metal and electrons just bounce off??

when do the electrons take the energy that was shined and jump excitedly to another state?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/how-does-the-photoelectric-effect-depend-on-the-frequency-of-the-light, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/photoelectric-effect-and-electron-loss

Answer (score 1):

First, electrons are not photons... to "bounce off" implies that the incident particle is an electron, and the electron bounces off. It is better to say the photon "knocks off" an electron.

Second, "do the electrons take the energy [from the light] and jump excitedly to another state?" Yes, that is correct. It is simplistic to say that electrons are simply knocked off; it is better to say *raised to a higher energy state*. However, for all practical purposes, beyond a few levels higher, it is effectively as if the electron were moved to "infinity". The [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) in metals is usually observed by the removal of electrons through a circuit, moving them far beyond their source.

In some cases it is easy to observe the electron being boosted to a higher energy level, and then relaxing back with emission of a photon, as in *[photoluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoluminescence)*. Zinc sulfide and calcium sulfide, for example, clearly demonstrate photoluminescence.